# What FastAPI admin dashboard connected with DynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, boto3, fastapi

I found that I could use FastAPI with DynamoDB by boto3.
But I couldn't see how I could implement the admin dashboard.
I can use the following packages:

- FlaskAdmin
- fastapi-admin
- sqlalchemy admin
- piccolo admin

But all of them are for SQL db.

Comment: What are those, Third-party packages?

Comment: @AlbertMarrero Yes. Thanks I will add information  about it.